# circular structure error when returning value in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I'd need some help on setting up my rest routes in Node + Express.

My problem is as follows:

controller.js:

```
module.exports = {
  findAll: function(req, res) {
    var users = User.findAll();
    res.json(users);
  }

};
```

User.js:

```
module.exports = {

  findAll: function(req, res) {
    userModel.user.find(function(err, user) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(user);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }

};
```

This console.logs me the users as expected, but if I change the console.log bit to return:

```
  findAll: function(req, res) {
    return userModel.user.find(function(err, user) {
      if (!err) {
        return user;
      } else {
        return console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

it gives me an error:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>       at Object.stringify (native)
>       at ServerResponse.res.json...

I don't see where I would have any circular structures.. I'm using Mongoose and, like said, everything works ok as long as I only console.log the userlist, but as soon as I try to return it to my controller it fails... What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just return a value inside an asynchronous execution context

The problem is with this line:

```
var users = User.findAll();
```

`User.findAll();` returns a query object (before the request even happens).

so `res.json(users);` tries to stringify the query object which has circular structure.

#### [From the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find):

> #### Query#find([criteria], [callback])
>
> Finds documents.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `[criteria]` `<Object>` mongodb selector
>   `[callback]` `<Function>`
>
> **Returns:**
>
> `<Query>` this
>
> When no callback is passed, the query is not executed.
>
> ---

### Recommended solution

You can use [static methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics):

```
userSchema.statics.findAll = function (cb) {
  this.find(cb);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I have to change my controller to
  
  findAll: function(req, res) {
    User.findAll(req, res); 

and in my user.js I do 

  findAll: function(req, res) {
    userModel.user.find(function(err, user) {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(_.clone(user));
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }

Comment: @QlliOlli See my recommended solution

Comment: Ain't working with mongoose when using the native node.js driver. (for methods mongoose has not implemented yet)